# Save Microsoft Document(s) Java script API for desktop add-ins

Tags: excel, ms-word, ms-office, office-js, office-addins

Web versions for MS Office word, excel, power point documents are saved automatically online(even document name is not saved). Is there any common Java script API available for add-in's to save desktop versions word, excel, power point documents with default file name(without save as)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is. For example, in Excel web add-ins you can use the [save(saveBehavior)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.workbook?view=excel-js-preview#excel-excel-workbook-save-member(1)) method where you could pass the [save](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.savebehavior?view=excel-js-preview) value which allows to save the workbook without prompting the user. If file is not saved, it will save it with default name in the default location.

You can file a new feature request at https://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions for other Office applications (Excel and PowerPoint).

Comment: But PPT and Word haven't similar APIs yet.

Comment: @MSFT-Jipyua is there any plans for them? Why do we get that difference between hosts?

Comment: hi Eugene, We track Office Add-in feature requests on our [Microsoft 365 Developer Platform Ideas Forum](https://aka.ms/m365dev-suggestions). Please add your request there. Feature requests are considered when we go through our planning process. Thanks.